# Python | return 400 through custom exception

Tags: python, flask

I've written one custom exception handling class to validate the input request data and raising it while validation is being failed. This is a Flask application. This seems to be working till the time server hasn't dispatched the response as I can see the exception object has a custom error but then it's being converted to a generic 500 error message. Am I missing something here are doing wrong?

```
class CustException(Exception):
    pass

class APIException(CustException):
    def __init__(self, status=None, title=None, type=None, detail=None, **kwargs):
        super(AIVException, self).__init__(detail)
        self.status = status
        self.detail = detail
        self.title = title
        self.type = type

if x not in [1, 2]:
    raise APIException(status=400, title='Bad request', type=default_type, detail="pass the correct value")
```

**

> Note - I want this to do by raising an exception instead of using
>   error handler. So please don't mark it duplicate.

**

Comment: why do you have `.__init__(detail)` when the super class does not have a constructor?

Comment: I was trying some combinations so mistakenly it's left. But it doesn't affect the response. isn't?

Comment: so if there is error in syntax then you would see a 500 error. try using `.__init__()` instead of `.__init__(detail)` and see if you still get 500

Comment: @AbtPst - Didn't work after removing super call.

Comment: you can keep the super call, but the constructor should be empty

Comment: @AbtPst - I meant same in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [errorhandler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler) decorator if you want to use APIException to return a custom message or something

```
@app.errorhandler(APIException)
def api_exception(ex):
    return 'Your custom message', your_code
```